# Forced symbol for the file with JSDoc `@name` returns an error that it does not exist

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

It is the code from the documentation (https://jsdoc.app/tags-name.html):

```js
// @ts-check
/**
 * @name highlightSearchTerm
 * @function
 * @global
 * @param {string} term - The search term to highlight.
 */
 eval("window.highlightSearchTerm = function(term) {};")

 window.highlightSearchTerm("");
```

But it still returns an error:

```
Property 'highlightSearchTerm' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.ts(2339)
```

Live inline example - https://codesandbox.io/s/jsdoc-name-test-1u224k?file=/src/index.js (locally in VSCode there is the same error)

**QUESTION:** Why does `@name` not work? What should I replace it with?

My target code is supposed to be like this:

```js
// @ts-check
/**
 * @name highlightSearchTerm
 * @function
 * @global
 * @param {string} term - The search term to highlight.
 */

 highlightSearchTerm("");
```

...because it's a function from another file, it uses in userScript, but so far even the version with `window` doesn't work.